# Setting up New Relic for Railo 4.x on Windows

Tags: java, tomcat7, newrelic, railo

I will like to setup performance monitoring on an application running on Railo 4 using New Relic. I have consulted the java docs on Railo, Railo google groups, etc but no one seems to have a perfect step by step.

Here is what I have done so far:

1. Extracted newrelic into Railo's install folder.
2. Added this line to setenv.sh

   `export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -javaagent:c/railo/newrelic/newrelic.jar"`
3. Restarted the Railo-Tomcat service
4. Added this line to the onapplicationstart function

   `application.NewRelic = createObject( "java", "com.newrelic.api.agent.NewRelic" );`
5. Added this line to the onrequeststart function

   `if ( structKeyExists( application, "NewRelic" ) ) {
       application.NewRelic.setTransactionName( "CFML", CGI.SCRIPT_NAME );
   }`

My application is still not sending metrics to New Relic. I will appreciate a step by step instruction of what to do as I can't seem to find that anywhere else and I have no idea what to do.

Comment: So does step 4 work - i.e. if you `dump(Application.NewRelic)` are you getting the Java object or what?

Comment: @PeterBoughton Yes it works. I get a Java Object with a number of methods.

Comment: I don't think Windows will execute the setenv.sh file.  That is a Unix bash script.

Answer (score 0):

We have more detailed instructions for installing with our supported platforms and frameworks in our documentation.  To see a list of the supported frameworks we are compatible with check out https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/java/new-relic-for-java#h2-compatibility

We may be able to work with the Tomcat portion of your environment and you can find helpful installation information at https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/java/java-agent-manual-installation

Should you run into any obstacles, I suggest opening a ticket at http://support.newrelic.com

Comment: Clearly, I have read all that and followed the instructions :(

Answer (score 0):

You can't use setenv.sh on Windows.  Instead modify the catalina.bat file, or use the Configure Tomcat utility in the Start Menu to set the javaagent option.  These steps can be found in more detail in the [New Relic documentation](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/java/tomcat-installation-for-java)